# grails how to set a default value to a date

Tags: grails

if we have a domain object, e.g. sales transaction, we want the date the sale was made to be now.  Ideally, the calling code should not even be able to set the property, but this is presumably not possible.

If we consider the following object:

```
class salesTransaction{
  String description
  Item item
  Date soldAt

static constraintes = {
    description blank: false
    item blank: false
    soldAt blank: false, defaultValue: new Date()
}
```

This looks like it should work, but save() always fails with property soldAt cannot be blank.

If I were doing this bean in Java, I would only expose a single constructor which only took the required parameters, and setters for the optionals, and no setter for soldAt.  I assume there is no way to simulate this with grails.

anyway, anyohne know how to do default parameters?

The best solution would be to do it in the DB, i.e. set a default value in the db to  "now()", but this is not possible to specify with grails constraints.

How do people go about implementing this kind of thing?

Comment: Define the property as `Date soldAt = new Date()` and that will make the default value of any instance be the current date and time that the instance is new'ed.

Comment: you can create constructor as you described, don't see any problem here. did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the date to represent the time that you initially saved the SalesTransaction to the database you can just declare a property like `Date dateCreated` and let the framework manage its value.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping for more information on that.

Comment: Not ideal, as doesnt set the corresponding default/constraint in the DB, but solves the immediate requirement, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the beforeInsert event:

```
class salesTransaction{
  String description
  Item item
  Date soldAt

static constraintes = {
    description blank: false
    item blank: false
    soldAt blank: false
}

def beforeInsert() {
    if (soldAt == NULL_DATE) {
         soldAt = new Date()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The auto timestamping does this for you.  There isn’t anything in the original question here that suggests that the extra code here is justified, but maybe there are factors that weren’t described which are important.  If you are going to do this then you probably want to configure soldAt to be bindable:false so it isn’t subject to mass data binding.  Also your blank:false for a Date property is non-sensical.  The blank constraint only makes sense in the context of a String property.

Comment: To follow up on the blank:false not being applicable here (I ran out of characters in previous comment), see https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/337e78161942f5a0164e7649b00e81f81f189922/grails-validation/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/BlankConstraint.java#L36.

Comment: I see the above example would be useful, but does not stop the user of the domain object setting the soldAt value to anything he wants.  In Java, I would not expose the soldAt at all with a setter, only a getter, and set soldAt to be new Date() in the constructor, and I would make the column not null in the Schema with a default of now().  I guess there is no way to do either of these in Grails.